# Does the following property of the composition of a magma have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity, magma

If $M$ is a magma and

$$+:M\times M\to M$$

is its law of composition, does the property

$$(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)\qquad\forall\ x,y,z\in M :\quad y\neq x,z$$

have a name? It resembles the associativity of the law, with the denoted exceptions.

Comment: Hi! Can you reference where you found this property? It is definitely a restriction of associativity.

Comment: I was studying the algebraic structure of a set endowed with a "superposition" law of composition, with the aim of representing algebraically the intuitive concept of a superposition of elements. I found out that, although it can be thought at first that the minimal structure would be that of a commutative semigroup, the associativity property conflicts with the obvious request that the superposition (i.e. the composition) of an element with itself be the element itself and the superposition between two different elements be a third element, different from the former two.

Comment: If, however, you state the associativity to be respected with the exception that I gave above, the conflict is solved.